# Show Feature vector on 3d mesh

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, optimization, computational-complexity, python

My case is as following:

I'm trying to extract features from mesh (vertices and faces), for example I had obtained zernike moments

```
 0.16402911 0.29690689 0.26002601 0.12894862 0.07586501 0.48601007
 0.45855364 0.20280874 0.0126834  0.54532024 0.46835978 0.34243193
 0.13314587 0.09234412 0.03764165 0.159134   0.45475221 0.1222509
 0.17898168]
```

and fourier transform like following

```
[[602.983833    +0.j          68.2650495 +308.71994353j
   68.2650495 -308.71994353j]
 [-76.48185048 +58.97442939j -41.7166658  +68.44586843j
  -65.40655281 +99.04981891j]
 [-70.793392   +31.66322377j -78.84787903  +0.77550291j
  -44.83406506  +0.51857595j]
 ...
 [-44.23448408 +10.60125082j -26.79330393 +12.57477038j
  -37.14294225 +40.98371836j]
 [-70.793392   -31.66322377j -44.83406506  -0.51857595j
  -78.84787903  -0.77550291j]
 [-76.48185048 -58.97442939j -65.40655281 -99.04981891j
  -41.7166658  -68.44586843j]]
```

The idea now is that I need to show these features on the mesh!

What I heard about is needing to obtain feature points from these data to be able to colorize the vertices with another color for example, and show them.

How to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was only about making some interpolation since these values are for specific vertices, and it needed other values for the rest vertices.

Using **vtkplotter library** in python, with the interpolation, it was well to do it.